# Facebook - Missing post

Tags: facebook, feed

Is there a way to post on own page without the word via xxxx?
Plus the post aren't showing on the Page itself..

I found the feed through
https: //graph.facebook.com/app_id/feed?access_token

and view it by passing the post id into
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

from there only found the post as http://www.facebook.com/195116460556019/posts/261775633890101

the code i had been using is all from the one i can find.. though most of them look alike..
the scope is " scope=read_stream,publish_stream,manage_pages "

```
<script>
//API init code is omitted
var wallPost = {
    access_token: "token",
    message: 'Hello, world!'
};

FB.api('/app_id/posts', 'post', wallPost, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occurred');
        console.log(response.error);
    } else {
        alert('Success!');
    }
});
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there a way to post on own page without the word via xxxx"

Nope, this is by design.  It is to let the viewer know where the posting came from.  It is purposely done to prevent applications from becoming "spammy".

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the quick response. but i still don't understand why the feed won't appear on the page itself.. =/